# Please I want to upload two files simultaneously and add info to mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Please I want to upload two files simultaneously and add info to mySQL, I dont know where i'm doing it wrong. Please help me out here, below is my code
`

```
$name = $_POST['music_name'];
$uploader = $_POST['music_uploader'];
$artist = $_POST['music_artist'];
$lyrics  = $_POST['music_lyrics'];
$file = (starz_hit_cf)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
$art = (art_for)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$art_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$folder="../downloads/";
$art_hold="../../assets/img/arts/";

// new file size in KB
$new_size = $file_size/1024;  
// new file size in KB

// make file name in lower case
$new_file_name = strtolower($file);
$new_art_name = strtolower($art);
// make file name in lower case

$final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
$final_art=str_replace(' ','-',$new_art_name);
$date =date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
if(move_uploaded_file($art_loc,$art_hold.$final_art))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_music (musicName,musicUploader,musicArtist,musicLyrics,musicfile,musicArt,musicType,musicSize,musicDate) VALUES('$name','$uploader','$lyrics','$final_file','$final_art','$file_type','$new_size','$date')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('successfully uploaded');
    window.location.href='index?success';
    </script>
    <?php
}
else
{
    ?>
    <script>
    alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='index?fail';
    </script>
    <?php
}
}
?>
```

Your kind reply is appreciated Thanks.

Comment: Before I review the code, Is your issue with the upload, with inserting the data into the database or both?

Comment: there are not 2 file here.

Comment: Thanks Sharron for your reply, The cod was working perfectly when i used it for one file but when i added the second file functions, that is the one with  `$art` and its related function, I only see blank page, ie the script holding the code `upload.php so i guess it's both

Comment: Sharon there are two files `$file = (starz_hit_cf)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];` and 
`$art = (art_for)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];` unless i didn't place them well please i need help

Comment: Be aware that the mysql_ extension was ***DEPRECATED*** in version 5.5 of PHP and was ***REMOVED*** from version 7.0 of PHP. You should now be using either the mysqli_ extension (note the i there) or PDO. When using any data that is being plugged into a query, having been sanitized/validated you should use prepared statements

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the HTML for the form (at least the part relating to the files being uploaded).

Comment: $_FILES['file']['name'] is not going to return different values just because it appears in two different lines of code...

Comment: Thanks Shadow, But how can I make it happen